# Unique validation of a substring in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am storing `filenames + their extensions` under `filename` column in the `files` table. My problem is, that since **only the name is present in the `$request` object without it's corresponding extension**, I can't validate the filename using unique validation rule without tinkering with the input data first. Example:

```php
// . . .
$this->validate($request, [
    //   Suppose the name of uploaded file is 'file'.
    // The below rule will NEVER fail, because in the 
    // database, similar file will be stored as 'file.txt',
    // thus 'file' != 'file.txt'
    'filename' => 'unique:files'
]);
// . . .
```

Is there a way to validate the filename ignoring it's suffix (extension) in the database?

Comment: Where in your code do you append an extension to the file name?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu after validations are passed, I concatenate the filename and it's extension and store them in the database. That's a fairly beefy piece of code, is it really needed to be posted here?

Comment: That depends, I may have a solution for you, but it relies on you changing strategy, which means stopping appending the extension AFTER validation and do it BEFORE.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice you were using `$this->validate` method instead of `Form Request` validation. Given that reality, can't you append the extension right before you call `$this->validate` instead of right after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to override the `all()` method in your `Request` class and append your extension **before validation instead of after**. That would be something like this

```
public function all() {
    $data = parent::all();           // Get all the data in your request
    $data['filename'] .=  '.txt';    // Concatenate the file extension

    return $data;           // DONT FORGET TO RETURN THE CHANGED DATA
}
```

Now, your rule will work properly because it will search for the file **with** the extension. **Reminder**: You'll need to stop appending the extension in your Controller or whichever place you use to do so, otherwise you'll end up with `filename.txt.txt` and will be back to square 1.

Personally, I find it a little messy to override the `all()` method whenever I feel like it, so I have the following trait

```
trait SanitizeRequest {

    protected $sanitized = false;

    public function all() {
        return $this->sanitize(parent::all());
    }

    protected function sanitize(array $inputs) {
        if ($this->sanitized) return $inputs;

        foreach ($inputs as $field => $value) {
            if (method_exists($this, $field))
                $inputs[$field] = $this->$field($value);
        }
        $this->replace($inputs);
        $this->sanitized = true;
        return $inputs;
    }

}
```

This trait allows me to write a custom method with the field name whenever I want to sanitize it before validation. Using this approach allows you to have a method like this

```
class YourRequest extends Request {

    use SanitizeRequest;

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    ...

   protected function filename($value) {
       return $value . '.txt';
   }

}
```

Comment: You are the MVP. Thank you for such a neat solution!